# Laravel 5.6 - how to create a model factory with a vertical table?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6, laravel-testing

I am working on application that is made up of `Leads`, each `Lead` `-> hasMany ->` `Fields`. My application will accept an `infinite` amount of `whitelisted` fields. Some `Leads` will have a lot of `Fields`, others will have maybe around 5. Due to this, I've opted for the `Field` table to be vertical, rather than fit in all the fields I accept horizontally, and then run into MySQL errors down the line (table too wide, etc.)

Here's my structure:

**Lead Table**

```
id
...
```

**Field Table:**

```
id
lead_id
field_name
field_value
```

I have created a model factory for my `Lead` model, that automatically creates `5` random fields using `Faker`.

I have an array of `texts`, `numbers`, `dates` (etc) fields which my application accepts.

**Field Factory:**

```
...

$texts = config('fields.whitelist.text');
foreach ($texts as $text) {
    $fields[$text] = $faker->sentence();
}

...

$randomField = array_random(array_keys($fields));    

return [
    'field_name' => $randomField,
    'field_value' => $fields[$randomField],
];
```

I've been doing this:

```
$lead = factory(Lead::class)->create()
         ->each(function ($l) {
             $l->fields()->save(factory(Field::class, 5)->make());
         });
```

However, I now have a `minimum` array of `Fields` which each `Lead` must have. I have these `minimum` fields in another config.

Is it possible to automatically create the `x` minimum `Fields` on the vertical table, using a factory?

E.g.

**Minimum Fields**

```
first_name
date_of_birth
```

How can I write a factory to automatically create the following structure:

```
[
    'field_name' => 'first_name',
    'field_value' => '<random name>',
],
[
    'field_name' => 'date_of_birth',
    'field_value' => '<random date>',
],
```

Edit: and if possible, not insert duplicate `field_name` values. Not like it's 100% deal breaker, but I want to make sure I 100% know what data I am working with, so checking `x` number of duplicates I imagine would be a nightmare

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want each `Lead` to have those minimum fields, then add those fields to your `each()` closure. Like this:

```
$lead = factory(Lead::class)->create()->each(function ($lead) {
    $lead->fields()->createMany([
        'field_name' => 'first_name',
        'field_value' => $faker->firstName,
    ],
    [
        'field_name' => 'date_of_birth',
        'field_value' => $faker->dateTime(),
    ]);
    $lead->fields()->save(factory(Field::class, 3)->make());
});
```

I changed the `Field` factory to 3 because there are 2 fields from the "minimum fields" that are inserted for every `Lead`.

Comment: Ah - fantastic, I didn't think about that! However, a new issue that I've realised, would there be a way to avoid creating duplicates of the same field?

Comment: What do you mean by duplicates? Faker should prevent that the field_values are not duplicated but I thought the intention was for the field_name should be duplicated for each Lead.

Comment: I don't want the same `field_name` to be entered more than once for the same Lead. I have validation to prevent it in my controller, but I'm trying to unit test the same method

Comment: You can add a unique constraint in your database for that

Comment: Yeah I had originally thought about that, but then we have some other business requirements where a `Lead` may contain the same `Field` (same `field_name`), so that wouldn't work for us

Comment: It would work, you just need the unique constraint to be on multiple columns, most likely a combination of lead_id and field_name

Comment: Wouldn't it run into MySQL constraint issues (occasionally or constantly, not 100% sure) as Laravel wouldn't be aware of the unique mysql constraint, would it?

Comment: Faker has the `->unique()` method just for this https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker

Comment: Sorry, I think there's a bit of confusion. I am not concerned about duplicate random `values`, I am concerned about duplicate `keys`. I do not want to insert the same `field_name` more than once

Comment: You can enforce that at the database level with `$table->unique('field_name')` if you want it to be unique per `Lead` then do `$table->unique(['field_name', 'lead_id'])`. As far as Laravel being aware of this uniqueness, the `unique()` method in faker takes care of that. Checking constraints elsewhere in your application is outside the scope of this question but Laravel does have facilities for that.